# How do I edit the CSS of one blog post but not others to have a 5 Star Rating System?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rating-system

I recently created [**my own blog**](http://beingwellread.blogspot.com) using Google's Blogger.

When I have completed reading a particular book, I have a [**Book's I Read Section**](http://beingwellread.blogspot.com/p/books-ive-read.html) where I would like to have a static **5 Star Rating System** in place of some kind. Perhaps with **CSS**, I can target each book so I will be able to display from **1 to 5 Stars** for the visitor to see.

I'm not sure how to edit the **CSS** of individual blog posts so I can target these specific read books, if that's the best method, and would like any tips in creating an image which I could specify how much of the **5 stars** should be displayed (like 100% for 5 Stars, 80% for 4 Stars, 60% for 3 Stars, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

This method does **NOT** use **JavaScript**, **jQuery**, **CSS** or **CSS3**.

**To clarify:** It uses plain **ASCII Code** to provide the **STAR** requirements.

*Solid Star:* ★ 
ASCII Code for Solid Star: `&#9733;`

*Outline Star:* ☆ 
ASCII Code for Outline Star: `&#9734;`

**Live DEMO Follows (*sorry jsFiddle!*):**

---

**Book Title:** A Trip To The Dentist
**Book Author:** Yin Pain & Lord Howard Hurts
**Star Rating:** ★☆☆☆☆

---

---

**Book Title:** Chest Pain
**Book Author:** I. Coffalot
**Star Rating:** ★★☆☆☆

---

---

**Book Title:** Dealing With Skunks
**Book Author:** Stan Back
**Star Rating:** ★★★☆☆

---

---

**Book Title:** Real Eyes Realize Real Lies
**Book Author:** I.C. You
**Star Rating:** ★★★★☆

---

---

**Book Title:** Spots On The Wall
**Book Author:** Who Flung Poo
**Star Rating:** ★★★★★

---

**HTML markup for above:**

```html
Book Title: A Trip To The Dentist<br />
Book Author: Yin Pain & Lord Howard Hurts<br />
Star Rating: &#9733;&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;<br />

Book Title: Chest Pain<br />
Book Author: I. Coffalot<br />
Star Rating: &#9733;&#9733;&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;<br />

Book Title: Dealing With Skunks<br />
Book Author: Stan Back<br />
Star Rating: &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9734;&#9734;<br />

Book Title: Real Eyes Realize Real Lies<br />
Book Author: I.C. You<br />
Star Rating: &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9734;<br />

Book Title: Spots On The Wall<br />
Book Author: Who Flung Poo<br />
Star Rating: &#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;<br />
```

### ★☆☆☆☆   ★★☆☆☆   ★★★☆☆   ★★★★☆   ★★★★★

***Optional:** Use `CSS font properties` to change star size, color, and background to customize it!*

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS of a specific tag using the `style` attribute:

```
<span class="stars" style="width: 80px"></span>
```

The `.stars` class could look like this:

```
background: url(stars.png) repeat-x;
```

Where `stars.png` is a 20px wide image, then repeated on the x dimension 4 times (80px) for 4 stars. 5 stars would be 100px width, etc.

---

*The general idea above is realized in this jsFiddle Demo, complete with tutorial comments.*

**Reference:**

[**jsFiddle Demo featuring Repeatable Star Rating CSS Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6aHd/)

**Screenshot:** 
[image]

Comment: Where do I put the actual CSS? I put the span thing in the actual post, but I'm not sure where the CSS stars stuff goes. Also, is the CSS code supposed to look like this:

stars {background:url(stars.png) repeat-x;}

Comment: Also, how do I remove the background of the image? I don't want a white background because my blog has a tan colored background.

Comment: **+1** Great concept Mr. Ian Wetherbee! That said, it's the best method that uses the most minimal CSS markup to create a customized **Stars Rating System** that the OP is looking for. Contribution to your answer is a jsFiddle and fiddle screenshot. Cheers!

Comment: @user1493950, I converted this Answer to a jsFiddle Tutorial for you to learn from. If you have any questions about this fiddle, continue to ask here and somebody shall reply. IMHO this is the best Answer that allows for a ***customized*** **5 Star Rating System** for your particular "static star" requirements that would be the **fastest** to setup, run, and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Use a jQuery **Star Rating Plugin**.
See 2nd-half for **CSS only** method.

Here's a screenshot from the [**jQuery Star Rating Plugin**](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing). The ***Database Integration Tab*** has more plugin examples and you can always search for more jQuery Star Plugins [**HERE**](http://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+star+rating+plugin) if you need that.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[**jsFiddle Demo for jQuery Star Rating Plugin**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXACN/)

**Screenshot of jsFiddle jQuery Star Rating Demo:**

[image]

Minimal HTML markup that the **jQuery Star Rating Plugin** uses (*extremely configurable*):

```html
<span class="bookFiveStar">
  <input name="book002" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
  <input name="book002" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
  <input name="book002" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
  <input name="book002" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
  <input name="book002" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
</span>
```

---

*Above and below are TWO very different solutions for this Answer.*

---

Use a **Pure CSS Rating System** without jQuery plugin or JavaScript.
See 1st-half above for jQuery Star Rating Plugin method.

Reference image used was from [**hot-linkable**](http://img366.imageshack.us/img366/6441/stars.jpg) imageshack.us and is shown below. 
Dimensions are `width:98px;` and `height:143px;` and image type is `jpg`.

[image]

**Reference:**

[**jsFiddle Demo for Pure CSS Star Rating**](http://jsfiddle.net/BWrMd/)

**Screenshot of jsFiddle Pure CSS Demo:**

[image]

**Minimal HTML:**

```html
<div class="starsCSS">
  <img class="stars3" title="3 Stars" src="http://img366.imageshack.us/img366/6441/stars.jpg" alt="Star Rating Image" />
</div>
```

**Complete CSS:**

```CSS
/* This class name configures and positions the 6 star image block. */
.starsCSS{
  /* The width of the star block uses the entire star.jpg width */
  width: 98px;
  /* The height of the star block is LIMITED to 23px, i.e. 1 star row. */
  height: 23px;
  /* This overflow:hidden will ensure only 1 row is ever seen, when aligned properly.
  /* That said, later below different classname uses margin-top negitive offset to align. */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* The placement of the star block is relative to other elements. Adjust px here. */
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 155px;
  /* Simple light blue border is provided for the image./
  /* Your cusom star image may be a .png with transparency so remove this setting. */
  border: 2px solid DodgerBlue;
}

/* This CSS Selector consists of classname .starsCSS that has 'img tag'. */
/* This rule will set original image width and original image height for stars.jpg file. */
.starsCSS img{
  width: 98px;
  height: 143px;
}

/* These 6 classes will position the image so that only the relevant "star row" is seen for .starsCSS */
/* Technically, this first class .stars1 is not needed since nothing changes. */
/* Note stars.jpg is used full width (98px), therefore it's 1 column. */
/* Use margin-left with negative value if your custom image.jpg has 2 or more columns */
/* IF stars.jpg was double in width then "margin-left: -98px;" will hide first column */
.stars1{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
/* Reference Image: 143px height divide by 6 star rows = 23.833333px per row. */
/* Hence, star.jpg image is not perfect and it's rounded to 24px per row instead */
/* Since 1 star row is 24px high, classname .stars2 will offset that to get to next row. */
/* That said, the value needs to be negitive since entire image is shifted up (offset). */
/* The class .starsCSS will now show the second star row! */
.stars2{
  margin-top: -24px; /* Shift up star row 1 */
}
.stars3{
  margin-top: -48px; /* Shift up star rows 1 and 2 */
}
.stars4{
  margin-top: -72px; /* Shift 3 rows of stars out of view (24 x 3 = 72 )  */
}
.stars5{
  margin-top: -96px; /* Shift 4 rows of stars out of view */
}
.stars6{
  margin-top: -120px; /* Shift 5 rows of stars out of view */
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking for something for visitors to my site to use to rate the site, I'm looking for a way to rate books, so I want to set the number of stars and leave it static

Comment: The **jQuery Star Rating Plugin** has a `disabled` mode where the rating is only set by you and can never be touched or altered by any user. This is why **Rating 6** in the photo does not have a red star, since I could not set it. See that **jsFiddle jQuery DEMO** to see a live example and learn more.

Comment: The **Pure CSS Star Rating System** has also been created and is part of my Answer. This method uses a single image to show from 1 to 6 stars. Create your own image `star.jpg` file for a 5 star version. See that **jsFiddle Pure CSS DEMO** to to see a live example and learn more.

Comment: Here's an alternate [**jQuery Star Rating Plugin**](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/) to consider.