# Make permanent position of arrow with CSS without affect text alignment from table cell

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table like:

```
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr class="example">
                <th>
                    <span id="item1">
                      <span>Value1</span>
                      <span class="sort-up no-display">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <span id="item2">
                       <span>Value2</span>
                       <span class="sort-up no-display">&nbsp;</span>
                    </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Example 1</td>
                <td>Example 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Example 3</td>
                <td>Example 4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

in header, I have an hidden up arrow which appears when at mouseover/mouseout with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
            $(".example th").on("mouseover mouseout", function(){
               var $sort_up = $(this).children().find("span").first().next();

                $sort_up.toggleClass("no-display");
            });
      });

</script>
```

where `no-display` is `display:none` css.

The screenshots (before)

[image]

And after:

[image]

I want that header title to not be moved at mouseover/mouseout event.

How to do that ? Maybe is a CSS trick.

PS: Maybe like:

[image]

Thanks for your patience with me that I have no more knowledge in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you're using an image to create the arrow, which then leads to the alignment problems; if you use `text()` to create a textual arrow, the infamous unicode upwards pointing triangle, then the alignment will maintain itself:

```
$('.example th').on('mouseover mouseout',
                     function(e){
                         var evt = e.type,
                             sort = $(this).find('span:last');
                         if (evt == 'mouseover'){
                             sort.text('▲');
                         }
                         else if (evt == 'mouseout') {
                             sort.text('');
                         }
                     });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MTQ4X/).

Comment: There could be thousands of reasons to use something else than a textual element (even if this remains a good practice)...

Comment: There could be, and there are, but without explanation as to *why* I still remain 'unsure.' I'm not intending to discount the validity of using images for this, but it seems unnecessarily complicated to do so, given that it leads to problems that using text neatly avoids.

Comment: @DavidThomas, I just used ASCII Code in this [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11307273/1195891) for a 5 Star Rating System. It serves it's purpose well with no CSS to boot!

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes

```
<span id="Val">Value2</span>
#Val{position:absolute;} Add top and left as per your need.
```

Now, it will remanin fixed even when your arrow appears.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS property to get it out of the [html flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293340/what-is-the-means-of-terms-normal-flow-and-out-of-flow-in-terms-of-html-cs); either [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) or [`float: right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float).