# Star rating ★★★☆☆ CSS for outlook 2010

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, rating-system

I would like to create a star rating system for outlook 2010 (email) , I send an email at the customer for evaluate the solution (5 star rating with link html : bad , good, very good ... )

Same of http://yefomit.com/internet/simple_css_rater but compatible with outlook 2010 (outlook block css)
Thanks to all

Comment: Please see my [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11307273/1195891) that shows how to use **ASCII Characters** that can be a building block for your rating system.

Comment: hi, thank you arttronics . But Outlook block the css , and it's not possbile to make an effect with the mouse (star empty and filled). Have you an idea ?

Comment: Please review that Answer again, as CSS is **not** used. It's just Text Characters like in your Questions title. Cheers!

Comment: Very short answer... It is not possible without some sort of outlook or browser based plug-in for any mainstream email service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to go with sarah's answer. You will need to create anchor controls around the normal starts with one star, two star up to five star, where when user clicks on a rating you will redirect him to some page on your own website with the rating mentioned...

That would be the easiest method to do it...

Comment: Yes I think it's more easy. Thanks all